# Overriding flutter class property only on specific environments

Tags: flutter, dart

Im new to flutter/dart and OOP style of coding in general. I am using a library called `flutter:inappwebview` to render webviews

```
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: InAppWebView(
                initialUrl: widget.url,
                onReceivedServerTrustAuthRequest:
                    (InAppWebViewController controller,
                        ServerTrustChallenge challenge) async {
                  return ServerTrustAuthResponse(
                      action: ServerTrustAuthResponseAction.PROCEED);
                },
              ),
            ),
```

I want to override the `onReceivedServerTrustAuthRequest` property only in dev environments otherwise fallback to default logic

Is there a way i can achieve this or do i need to build two different widgets altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditionals in your layout and the flutter foundation package to determine if your app is in debug mode. This would look like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' as foundation;

          child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: InAppWebView(
                initialUrl: widget.url,
                onReceivedServerTrustAuthRequest: (foundation.kDebugMode) ? 
                   (InAppWebViewController controller, ServerTrustChallenge challenge) 
                     async {
                       return ServerTrustAuthResponse(
                        action: ServerTrustAuthResponseAction.PROCEED);
                     } : null,
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: ah , will this fallback to the default property or will it return null on non dev builds?

Comment: It depends if the `InAppWebView` checks if the given param is null. If the widget does something like `widget.onReceivedServerTrustAuthRequest ?? //normal logic` it should just execute the normal behavior. You can F12 in VS code on inappwebview and see how it handles the parameters. Most widgets do check this way though, I'd give it a try.

Comment: I just looked in the documentation of `InAppWebView`. This doesn't actually seem to have a default value so passing null wouldn't change the effects at all in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for checking - will try and see if this will work